# run perl script with python

Tags: python, linux, perl

I've been looking at multiple examples on here and elsewhere, but nothing seems for work for me. I know nothing about python. All I am trying to do is run a perl script simply located at

```
sdb1/media/process.pl
```

The example code that I've found runs all over the place, and mostly seems like it has extra stuff that I don't need. What I'm trying right now is

```
#! /usr/bin/python
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "/sdb1/media/process.pl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But that just gives me the error

```
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined
```

If I've missed anything important, let me know. Otherwise, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to import the subprocess library to run subprocess

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "/sdb1/media/process.pl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Too easy. Thanks. I have to wait 8 more minutes before I can accept it.

Comment: One lingering question... When I run the perl script through command line, it executes the whole way through. When I do it through python, it hangs after the first line. Is there a simple solution to that?

Comment: never mind. I figured it out. I just changed it to
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you are just using that same function a lot of times, you can do

```
from subprocess import Popen
```

then you can just call

```
pipe = Popen(["perl", "/sdb1/media/process.pl"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I would have commented but I need 50 rep.